# Maintain user details in session using struts2

Tags: session, struts2

I have a struts2 application. In my application i maintain a session using

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("login","true");
session.put("username",getUname1());
session.put("balance",balance);
```

this way.

If one user can login there is a no problem to get user name and balance.If suppose more than one user can login, how will i get the balance for corresponding login user.

Please any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't use name use unique identifier to identify the user.

Comment: ok.then how will i display username in another jsp page or anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried to login more than one user? Please read about technologies you are using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html.

Comment: What is the balance ? Which is the question ?

Comment: balance is another one value.it is stored in map when the user has login.the question is if more than one user can login,how will i get the balance for logeed user?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bother. The session is unique for each users. When you will try to get the value of balance for the user, you will get the value you set when he logged in. You won't be able to get the value of balance of an other user through the session.